# How to fix that overlapping XML?

Tags: c++, python, xml, regex, bash

I have a problem. I am making some changes in XML code but sometimes it gets overlapped like:

```
<xref><mytag></xref></mytag>
```

I am thinking about a script that will parse XML file and fix that problem like:

```
<xref><mytag></mytag></xref><mytag></mytag>
```

Can anyone help my with that? Maybe some regular expression? Or some tool ready for use, python script etc. I got many files to fix and I will appreciate every advice!s

Comment: How are you editing XML? C++? Python? Which library (if any)?

Comment: there is a Python script which adds <mytag>some text</mytag>

Comment: And you cannot fix that python script to output correct XML?

Comment: Best solution is to make your changes using an XML editor that would not allow such errors to creep in in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/); the library can make an attempt at parsing your invalid XML and clean it up, by setting the `recover` flag:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> ex = '<xref><mytag>there is some text</xref></mytag>'
>>> parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
>>> tree = etree.parse(StringIO(ex), parser)
>>> etree.tostring(tree.getroot())
'<xref><mytag>there is some text</mytag></xref>'
```

Comment: Nice one. I've never used that recover flag

Comment: Hey, thanks for advice but the thing is between <mytag> there is some text</mytag> (it will be a link in final HTML document by <xref> and has some extra atributtes by <mytag>) so I am trying to figure out how to ADD extra tags <mytag> just to make XML files well-formed

Comment: Expand your example and let's see what lxml will make of it. Also, you are feeding invalid XML, so you cannot be too picky as to what automated tools will make of it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best tool for me to deal with xml in Python: [lxml](http://lxml.de/)

Your problem however, i'm afraid it can't be solved with lxml, since that xml is invalid. I encourage you to use some xml tool or library (lxml) to generate valid xmls and avoid this kind of issues.

Comment: Actually, it *can* be solved with lxml, as lxml can recover invalid XML.

Answer (score 0):

As for C++ you can use the POCO library XML (Document) features to edit your XML files: [Poco::XML::Document](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.XML.Document.html)